# UI feedback on android app (widgets)

Tags: discussion, android-app

I have used the android app for a while now, and I have to say that I like it.
I use it mostly for reading voting and commenting, but I have tried to do more (answering simple questions) and works way better than using the site on my handset.
I like to UI, it looks friendly, polished and.. kind of "unique". It definitely has the traits of an android app but it is not "copy" any of the existing apps.

This is why I really do NOT like it when you fall back to some standard android widget. Example: to vote up a comment, you tap on the (very nice) comment widget and it brings up a android popup menu, which I think is kind of ugly and disrupts the experience and the "polished" feeling (and it has a completely different color scheme, for example).
It feels like a javascript "alert" in the middle of a modern website to me.

There are other places where this transition between "SE look" to "standard android widgets" happen. I personally do not like it, and I hope it is due to the alpha version of the app, and will be fixed.
Of course, it is low priority because it works and it is only a minor improvement, but it struck me immediately as "not right".

Just my 2 cents!

Comment: Interesting. On every other device, a "custom" look would be a disadvantage. You would want to use native controls/widgets whenever possible for a consistent feeling and to maximize usability. For example, an iOS app that ignored common UI conventions and avoided standard widgets would be a giant flop. I can't imagine why the Android platform would be different. Are the native widgets *that bad*?

Comment: They are not that bad.. even if they constantly change from a version to the next so they are not perfect, not even in the Android designer's mind. 
I agree that, in general, I like my apps to have a consistent feeling with the system (I hate android apps with a "iphone" toolbar, for example), and the app HAVE a consistent "android" feeling, with all the right UI and navigation patterns. It is the "skin" that changes

Comment: And it is the transition that bothers me. Mind you, it is a minor annoyance as I said but all the graphics in the app is in nice gray and blue "soft" tones, and than bang! a white, flat-style menu with cyan borders.. Like I said, it feels like a bootstrap-ui website with a plain JS alert in the middle. All IMO, obviously!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. We are trying to use native widgets where available, but it's very possible that a lot of them have not been styled yet.